# Find the value in column X that corresponds to last missing value in column Y

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)),
                 b = c(NA, NA, "test", NA, "test", "test", NA, NA, "test"),
                 c = c("trial", "test", "trial", "trial", "test", "trial", "trial",
                       "trial", "trial"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Let's say df contains three variables - 1 group (a), 1 b-value and 1 c-value.

What I want is to find for each row the value in c column that corresponds to last missing value in the b column.

My expected output is what is in the try column.

```
+---------------------+
| try   a  b    c     |
+---------------------+
| trial a NA   trial  |
| test  a NA   test   |
| test  a test trial  |
| trial b NA   trial  |
| trial b test test   |
| trial b test trial  |
| trial c NA   trial  |
| trial c NA   trial  |
| trial c test trial  |
+---------------------+
```

Currently, I do a quick but inefficient loop which also doesn't allow me to group anything.

```
miss <- c()
try <- c()

for (i in 1:length(df$b)) {

  miss[i] <- max(which(is.na(df[1:i,]$b)))

  try[i] <- df[miss[i], 3]

}

new <- cbind(as.data.frame(try), df)
```

However, I would like to turn this either into a data.table or dplyr approach where I could eventually do this operation also per each group, on a large dataset, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`,

```
library(tidyverse)

#METHOD 1:
df %>% 
 group_by(a) %>% 
 mutate(new = tail(c[is.na(b)], 1), 
        new = replace(new, is.na(b), c[is.na(b)]))

#METHOD 2:
df %>% 
 group_by(a) %>% 
 mutate(new = replace(c, !is.na(b), NA)) %>% 
 fill(new)
```

Both giving,

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 4
> # Groups:   a [3]
>   a     b     c     new  
>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 a     <NA>  trial trial
> 2 a     <NA>  test  test 
> 3 a     test  trial test 
> 4 b     <NA>  trial trial
> 5 b     test  test  trial
> 6 b     test  trial trial
> 7 c     <NA>  trial trial
> 8 c     <NA>  trial trial
> 9 c     test  trial trial
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works, but especially 2nd approach is most of interest to me, since I want to handle cases with several separate non-empty rows per group. Due to bad experiences with tidyr's fill I'll just replace it with na.locf ;-) (it can take so long, even only with some thousand rows ..)